# How to modify e-mail template with gitlab in a Container

Tags: docker, gitlab

I would like to change the e-mail's template.
But I don't have any idea where is it...
The problem is that I have a reverse proxy nginx on the port 8443 and the container of Gitlab is on the classic port.
And when gitlab send e-mail like a new account, it sends the url without the port.
So I tried with external_link but I didn't modify the port in my nginx
thank you for your answer

Comment: Please read your question and ask yourself if it's understandable for any other person, thanks. Other than that, can you provide `docker run` command that you used?

Comment: Ok, I am going to be clear. I have a docker-compose with nginx and gitlab container. Currently, the port reachable is 8443 on the nginx. After, nginx redirects to the port 80 on gitlab. This works perfectly. But the problem is for the e-mail. Because it's send a url to access the git and the url doesn't have the port. So, how can I change this ? it's better ?